# Conditional rendering of things in component (ltr to rtl) with minimal duplication?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-i18n

I’m pretty new to vue so this may be a stupid question. I’m making a multilingual app using vue cli for both english language and arabic language, i’m using the vue-i18n plugin as well. Basically in my components I’ve got multiple things going on in the html template that I need to account for in terms of right to left if the user selects the arabic language. A very simplified example of what I have right now:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Some text</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
    <button type="button">Button</button>
</div>
</template>
```

What I need to do is also account for right to left for arabic so I need to align text to the right and put the button on the other side for example, I need to do this for all the code in my other components as well and not just a one off. So is there a better way to do this than using conditional rendering as follows as the code seems very repetitive?

```
<template>
<div v-if="language=arabic">
    <h1 text-align:right>{{ $t('message') }}</h1>
    <button type="button">Button</button>
    <p>{{ $t('lorem_ipsum') }}</p>
</div>

<div v-else>
    <h1>{{ $t('message') }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $t('lorem_ipsum') }}</p>
    <button type="button">Button</button>
</div>
</template>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use [css flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and then use [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/):

```
<template>
  <div :class="['has-translation', `has-translation--${this.i18n.locale}`]">
    <h1>{{ $t('message') }}</h1>
    <button type="button">Button</button>
    <p>{{ $t('lorem_ipsum') }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then on your CSS you can do:

```
.has-translations.has-translations--en {
  text-align: left;
}

.has-translations.has-translations--ar {
  text-align: right;
}
```

If you would like to align (read justify) all lines to the right or left you can:

```
.has-translations {
  display: flex;
}

.has-translations.has-translations--en {
  justify-content: left;
}

.has-translations.has-translations--ar {
  justify-content: right;
}
```

I haven't tested the code but this is a general idea I have used in my projects and worked great.

Comment: Thanks for this! Any idea how I would go about rearranging the layout as well? So as a basic example as per my post, if its english, i'd want my button to be on the right and left for arabic. The components are of course more complicated as well so would there be a good way to do this as well?

Comment: You could use the same idea as well. Whatever UI framework you are using most probably has some kind of `flex-order-inverse` class where it can invert the elements in a `div`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a lay-out related issue concering the base-structure of your application, my first thought would be to define this at the root of your applcication and not on every component. If your body has a class that define right-to-left, you can style you components accordingly. I don't think your vue-components need to know this information.